# Where to locate thread that manages the SurfaceView too

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, surfaceview

I have an activity that host some views: a SurfaceView, a SeekBar and some buttons. The SurfaceView display an animation and the other views control some parameter of the animation. I created a Thread inside the activity to run all these operations on all the views.

But all around the web I always found examples of SurfaceView that have their own thread in order to start it in surfaceCreated() and to stop it in surfaceDestroyed(), etc. But my thread is not thought only for the SurfaceView because other view partecipate or interact with the animation. So, where I have to put the Thread? In the SurfaceView class (and how to access other views from there)? Or in the Activity class like I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interaction between SurfaceView and the Activity lifecycle is not straightforward.  A full discussion of the issues can be found [in an appendix to the graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).

> This raises a fundamental question when using a separate renderer thread with SurfaceView: Should the lifespan of the thread be tied to that of the Surface or the Activity? The answer depends on what you want to have happen when the screen goes blank. There are two basic approaches: (1) start/stop the thread on Activity start/stop; (2) start/stop the thread on Surface create/destroy.

You can find examples of both approaches in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika). For example, the [HardwareScalerActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java) uses approach #2, creating and joining the render thread in the Surface callbacks.  [TextureFromCameraActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java) uses approach #1, because it's also managing the Camera.  In both cases there are edge cases you need to be aware of, e.g. HardwareScalerActivity starts the render thread and then waits for it to finish initializing before continuing.